# Swapping items in list using only add and remove

Tags: java, arrays, list, swap

I was wondering if something like this would work to swap around items in a list. 
Example: Initial items: M A I L -> Desired: L I A M

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < testList.size() ; i++ )
     testList.add( 0 , testList.remove (i));
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to run it?

Comment: I think it is valid. because after first iteration(i=1) it is AMIL, 2nd IAML.. and last LIAM.

Answer (score 3):

Your idiom works*, but `Collections.reverse(testList);` is the optimized way to do it.

Comment: Do you need to start at 0? Surely `testList.add(0, testList.remove(0))` is logically a no-op.

Comment: @AndyTurner nope nope nope. You're right. Need a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a valid solution for you (is `set` ok to use?)?

```
int i = 0;
int j = testList.size() - 1;

while (i < j) {
    int temp = testList.get(i);
    testList.set(i, testList.get(j));
    testList.set(j, temp);
    i++;
    j--;
}
```